# B-Tree Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes, b-tree

I am having a weird error where after my program executes the split method of the twoThreeTree (or B-Tree), the children become null, and any integer values saved in the new nodes that were created are gone (n1 and n2, and p if the node that was passed is the root). I have checked the values of root, root.left, and root.right (or p, p.left and p.right) at the very end of the split method numerous times and they are all fine, but the second the program exits the split method and returns to the insertItem method (ie. the split method is called on line 188 and I check the values again after the method has been called on line 189) the Node no longer has any integer values and its children are null.

twoThreeTree.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "twoThreeTree.h"

twoThreeTree::twoThreeTree() {
    root = NULL;
}

//helper method
void twoThreeTree::inOrder() {
    inOrder(root);
}

//modified recursive LVR in order traversal
void twoThreeTree::inOrder(Node* ptr){
    ...
    } //end else
}

/*
 *takes a leaf node with three values and gives the parent node the middle value.
 *calls itself recursively when the '3-Node'parent inherents an extra value
 */
void twoThreeTree::split(Node* ptr){
    toString(ptr);
    Node p;
    /*
     *special case, if the node passed is the root
     *else p is equal to the parent
     */
    if (ptr->parent == 0) {
        p = Node(ptr->middleValue);
        p.isLeaf = false;
    } //end if
    else {
        p = *ptr->parent;
    } //end else

    /*
     *two new nodes inhereting the small and large values of the 
     *inital node, the intial node will be dispoded of at the end of the method
     */
    Node* n1 = new Node(ptr->smallValue);
    Node* n2 = new Node(ptr->largeValue);
    int item = ptr->middleValue;

    /*
     *not neccessary. at the moment, only used to test for the root node
     */
    n1->parent = &p;
    n2->parent = &p;
    toString(n1);
    toString(n2);

    /*
     *will only happen with the recursive calls below. this segment splits a
     *'4-node' into two '2-nodes'
     */
    if (ptr->isLeaf == false) {
        n1->isLeaf = false;
        n2->isLeaf = false;
        n1->left = ptr->left;
        n1->right = ptr->middle;
        n2->left = ptr->right;
        n2->right = ptr->extra;
    } //end if
    /*
     *the parent will now temporarily become a '4-node' where-in its left child
     *equals the lowest value, middle second lowest, right second highest,
     *extra the highest value, and the '4-node' will be split again recursively
     */
    if (p.isThreeNode == true) {
        if (item < p.smallValue) {
            p.middleValue = p.smallValue;
            p.smallValue = item;
            p.extra = p.right;
            p.right = p.middle;
            p.left = n1;
            p.middle = n2;
        } //end if
        else if (item < p.largeValue) {
            p.middleValue = item;
            p.extra = p.right;
            p.right = n2;
            p.middle = n1;
        } //end else if
        else {   //item > p.largeValue
            p.middleValue = p.largeValue;
            p.largeValue = item;
            p.extra = n2;
            p.right = n1;
        } //end else
        split(&p); 
    } //end if
    /*
     *the parent will become a '3-Node' in this case. p.left and
     *p.right already exist and adjusting them is just a matter of understanding where
     *our current node is in relation to the parent (ie. if the item value is less than
     *p.smallvalue then we know the current node is to the left of the parent and the right
     *side does not need adjusting)
     */
    else if (p.parent != 0) { //p.isTwoNode == true
        p.isThreeNode = true;
        if (item < p.smallValue) {
            p.largeValue = p.smallValue;
            p.smallValue = item;
            p.left = n1;
            p.middle = n2;
        } //end if
        else { //item > p.smallValue
            p.largeValue = item;
            p.right = n2;
            p.middle = n1;
        } //end else
    } //end else
    /*
     *in this case the node passed to the method was the root and along with normal
     *splitting methods, the root must be changed
     */
    else {
        std::cout << "this one" << std::endl;
        p.left = n1;
        p.right = n2;
        root = &p;
        //delete ptr; do not know if this is neccesary
    }
} //end split

//helper method, special case for root
void twoThreeTree::insertItem(int item){
    if (root == NULL){
        root = new Node(item);
        return;
    }
    insertItem(root, item);
}

/*
 *will recursively call itself until a leaf node is hit. once a leaf
 *node is hit a value will be assigned, if a middle value is assigned the
 *node will be split
 */
void twoThreeTree::insertItem(Node* ptr, int item) {
    toString(ptr);
    if (ptr->smallValue == 0){
        std::cout << "small value equals zero" << std::endl;
        ptr->smallValue = item;
        return;
    }
    //locate the leaf in which the new item belongs
    if (ptr->isLeaf == true) {
        if (ptr->largeValue == 0) { 
            if (item > ptr->smallValue) {
                ptr->largeValue = item;
            } //end if
            else {  //the item is smaller than the smallValue
                ptr->largeValue = ptr->smallValue;
                ptr->smallValue = item;
            } //end else
        } //end if
        else {       //if there are two pieces of data
            if (item < ptr->smallValue) {
                ptr->middleValue = ptr->smallValue;
                ptr->smallValue = item;
            } //end if
            else if (item < ptr->largeValue) {
                ptr->middleValue = item;
            } //end else if
            else {
                ptr->middleValue = ptr->largeValue;
                ptr->largeValue = item;
            } //end else
            split(ptr);
        } //end else
    } //end if
    else if (ptr->isThreeNode == true) {
        if (item < ptr->smallValue) {
            insertItem(ptr->left, item);
        } //end if
        else if (item < ptr->largeValue) {
            insertItem(ptr->middle, item);
        } //end else if
        else { 
            insertItem(ptr->right, item);
        } //end else
    } //end else if
    else {
        if (item < ptr->smallValue) {
            insertItem(ptr->left, item);
        } //end if
        else { 
            insertItem(ptr->right, item);
        } //end else
    } //end else
} //end insertItem

void twoThreeTree::toString(Node* ptr){
    std::cout << "address: " << ptr << " small: " << ptr->smallValue << " middle: " << ptr->middleValue << " large: " << ptr->largeValue << std::endl;
}
```

twoThreeTree.h

```
#ifndef TWOTHREETREE_H
#define TWOTHREETREE_H

#include <iostream>

/*
 *node structure with 5 pointers
 */
struct Node {
    int     smallValue,
            middleValue,
            largeValue;
    Node*   left;
    Node*   middle;
    Node*   right;
    Node*   extra;
    Node*   parent;
    bool    isLeaf,
            isThreeNode;

    Node() {
        smallValue = 0;
        middleValue = 0;
        largeValue = 0;
        left = 0;
        middle = 0;
        right = 0;
        extra = 0;
        parent = 0;
        isLeaf = true;
        isThreeNode = false;
    }

    Node(int smallValue) {
        this->smallValue = smallValue;
        middleValue = 0;
        left = 0;
        middle = 0;
        right = 0;
        extra = 0;
        parent = 0;
        largeValue = 0;
        isLeaf = true;
        isThreeNode = false;
    }
};

class twoThreeTree {
    /*
private:
    Node root;
    void inOrder (Node& ref) {};
    void insertItem(Node& ref, int item) {};
    */
public: //all values temporarily public
    Node*root;
    void inOrder (Node* ptr);
    void insertItem(Node* ptr, int item);
    twoThreeTree();
    void inOrder();
    int  findItem(Node* ptr, int target);
    void split(Node* ptr);
    void toString(Node* ptr);
    void insertItem(int item);
};
#endif
```

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "twoThreeTree.h"

int main() {
    int size;
    std::cout << "Enter the size (between 2^6 and 2^13): "; //ignore any specified values
    std::cin >> size;
    int startingValue = rand() % 10000;
    twoThreeTree tree; //initialize twoThreeTreeClass
    tree.insertItem(startingValue); //not neccessary, done for debugging purposes
    std::cout << "starting value: " << startingValue << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int debug = rand() % 10000;
        std::cout << "random number: " << debug << std::endl;
        std::cout << "root address: " << tree.root << " root small value: " << tree.root->smallValue << std::endl;
        tree.insertItem(debug);
    }
    tree.inOrder();
}
```

A standard output is:
starting value:41
input: 8467
root: 0064A380 small: 41   mid: 0    large: 8467
input: 6334
--split--
root: 0064A380 small: 41   mid: 6334 large: 8467
n1:   0064A54A small: 41   mid: 0    large: 0
n2:   0064A5A8 small: 8467 " "
p: 0018F444 small: 6334 " "
root: 0018F444 small: 6334 " "
--main--
root: 0018F444 small:  -85899340 " "

really frustrating problem would appreciate any help shedding light on the issue

Comment: That is a lot of code. If you could try to create a [mcve], that would help tremendously.

Comment: You're storing addresses of local variables in your tree. You should have learned not to do that when you implemented simpler structures like linked lists and binary trees.